# how do I attach a javascript SDK function for Facebook to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api

from the facebook docs it reads I have to use the following following function:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
    // Person is now logged out
});
```

but how exactly do I attach it to a button?

Comment: could you link us to the facebook docs please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout

Comment: are you using any js framework/library in particular?

Comment: no, I followed the facebook developer guide on how to include javascript sdk from facebook in the html and then how to create login and like buttons, but for the logout button it just says use the above function and attach to a button or link (this is where I am confused about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using any Javascript library or framework then you will have to use the [Javascript onclick Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

First, wrap your `FB.logout()` function this way:

```
var logOut = function() {
  FB.logout(function(response) {
    // Person is now logged out
  });
};
```

and then attach this `logOut()` function to your desired button like this:

```
<button onclick="logOut()">Log Out</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your code separate from HTML. Meaning, you should not use onclick directly, better attach an event listener. For example:

```
<button id="logoutButton">Log Out</button>
```

JS Code:

```
document.getElementById('logoutButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        // Person is now logged out
    });
});
```